# NOT IN subquery takes too long to execute

Tags: mysql, mysql-slow-query-log

How do I optimize this query to get the same result, without taking as long? The `NOT IN` subquery takes a very long time.

```
SELECT DISTINCT EmployeeId FROM employees
    WHERE 
    status = 'Active' 
    && BranchId = '2' 
    && NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT * FROM attendance
      WHERE
      employees.EmployeeId = attendance.EmployeeId 
      && attendance.AttendanceDate = '2015-01-20'
    )
  )

SELECT EmployeeId FROM employees 
    WHERE 
    status = 'Active' 
    && BranchId = '2' 
    && NOT IN (
      SELECT EmployeeId FROM attendance WHERE AttendanceDate='2015-01-20'
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another version of your query

```
select
distinct e.EmployeeId FROM employees e
left join attendance a on e.EmployeeId = a.EmployeeId and a.AttendanceDate = '2015-01-20'
where
e.status='Active' 
and e.BranchId= '2' 
and a.EmployeeId is null
```

You will also need some indexes to be applied on the tables as

```
alter table employees add index st_br_idx(status,BranchId);
alter table AttendanceDate add index AttendanceDate_idx(AttendanceDate);
```

if EmployeeId is a foreign key then no need to add the index else if the
index is not already there you may need the following as well

```
alter table AttendanceDate add index EmployeeId_idx(EmployeeId);
```

If `EmployeeId` is a primary key in `employees` then its already indexed if not and not indexed you may need to add  index for that as well

```
alter table employees add index EmployeeId_idx(EmployeeId);
```

You may also check your original query after having above indexes

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.EmployeeId FROM employees e 
WHERE 
e.status='Active' 
and e.BranchId= '2' 
and NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM 
  attendance a WHERE e.EmployeeId = a.EmployeeId 
  and a.AttendanceDate='2015-01-20'
)
```

To analyze the query use `explain select..` and see how optimizer is using the indexes 
and possible number of rows the optimizer may scan for retrieving the records